# Which is best Postfix Log analyzer?

Tags: postfix-mta, log-analysis

Which is best Postfix Log analyzer? We are looking for good log analyzer for postfix. We need to analyze the following

1. How many mails queued ?
2. How many mails not delivered ?
3. Why mails are not delivered ?

And is it possible to view the subject for the all mail status instead of message id?
I mean to review the status of the single mail.

We are using Sawmill analyzer now. But the management is not satisfied with the report from the sawmaill, since its missing single message status and subject.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've used http://jimsun.linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html before. Give it a try =) may help you with what you need.

Comment: Consider setting up a daily cronjob to send you an e-mail report, e.g.

0 9 * * * /usr/local/bin/pflogsumm.pl -d yesterday --problems_first /var/log/maillog | mail -s "yesterday's mail activity" you@domain.com

Comment: apt-get install pflogsumm

Comment: This really is a great mail log analyzer!

Comment: I just recommend my tool for filtering output to pflogsumm - https://github.com/brablc/postfix-tools/blob/master/pflogrep . Tried to get it to http://jimsun.linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html but no response.

Answer (score 20):

Inspired by aimfeld, pflogsumm is really better and simpler to use:

Just install it using following commands.
For Debian/Ubuntu (https://packages.debian.org/sid/pflogsumm):

```
apt-get install pflogsumm
```

For RedHatLinux/RHEL, CentOS, Fedora:

```
yum install postfix-pflogsumm
```

Example usage, get today's summary by:

```
pflogsumm -d today /var/log/mail.log
```

good ref: https://calomel.org/pflogsumm.html

Links to documentation:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/pflogsumm

Comment: Important note from the FAQ. If you're processing multiple mail.log files at the same time, make sure to use `pflogsumm \`ls -rt /var/log/maillog*\``. pflogsumm relies on log messages "arriving" in the order in which they were created. Source: https://jimsun.linxnet.com/downloads/pflogsumm-faq.txt